# android llamada de actividad a fragmento

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Tengo una actividad desde la que cargo un fragmento u otro al pinchar en una notificación. El código es el siguiente:

```
public class Repeating_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();

    String tipoNotificacion = intent.getString("tipoNotificacion");

    if(tipoNotificacion.equals("1")){
        lanzarFragmentoMantenimientosVencidos();
    } else if(tipoNotificacion.equals("2")){
        lanzarFragmentoInspeccionesVencidas();
    }
}

private void lanzarFragmentoMantenimientosVencidos(){
    Mantenimientos_fragment mpf = new Mantenimientos_fragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("filtro", 2);
    mpf.setArguments(bundle);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContenedor, mpf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
private void lanzarFragmentoInspeccionesVencidas(){
    Inspecciones_fragment ipf = new Inspecciones_fragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("filtro", 2);
    ipf.setArguments(bundle);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.flContenedor, ipf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
 }
}
```

Depurando, no llega a ninguna clase de ningún fragmento y me dan los siguientes errores:

```
05-28 11:44:43.706 3922-3922/com.kastel.COSMA E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f080082 (com.kastel.COSMA:id/flContenedor) for fragment Mantenimientos_fragment{5c9c505 #1 id=0x7f080082}
```

-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kastel.COSMA/com.kastel.COSMA.notificaciones.Repeating_activity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080082 (com.kastel.COSMA:id/flContenedor) for fragment Mantenimientos_fragment{5c9c505 #1 id=0x7f080082}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que se muestra es debido a que no encuentra la vista en donde realizar la transacción del Fragment:

> FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f080082
>   (com.kastel.COSMA:id/flContenedor) for fragment
>   Mantenimientos_fragment{5c9c505 #1

**`R.id.flContenedor` no existe en el layout que cargas en la `Activity` mediante `setContentView()`**

Puedes agregar en el layout un `FrameLayout` con id `flContenedor` y de esta forma se mostraría tu `Fragment`.

Comment: y qué podría hacer? Solo es una clase "puente", solo tiene el código que he puesto. Gracias!

Comment: Puedes agregar en el layout un FrameLayout con id flContenedor y de esta forma se mostraría tu Fragment.

Comment: gracias, funciona!

Comment: @Juan excelente juan, saludos!